# Android Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020052

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I suddenly started facing below exception on app testing and app is crashing

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
#0x7f020052
```

I searched and found some solution and implemented but no luck.
below is gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.gswi.bollywood"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    // Stops the Gradle plugin’s automatic rasterization of vectors
    generatedDensities = []

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true

}

// Flag to tell aapt to keep the attribute ids around
aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I am providing error 
**Log cat:**

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020052
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1883)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:723)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:525)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:74)
            at com.gswi.bollywood.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
            at 

    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
                at  

    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the entire log?

Comment: clean and rebuild may solve it

Comment: show complete logcat error log.

Comment: Did clean and rebuild but no luck

Comment: are you using vector drawables? which api level you are using to compile your project? android does not support vector drawables prior api level 16.

Comment: Minimum sdk version is 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really I hate to reply my own question but I would like to share what worked for me to come out from this gravely situation. Actually
I was using `Android studio 1.3` version after updating/installing `Android studio 2.2.2` error resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is such a way is you have to find this value stored in your auto generated R.java file "[image: #0x7f020052]" then find that assigned resource value which is "arrow" is missing in your project.

it can be restored by clean and rebuld project. Even if it does not help you try to backup your project and then try to delete usesage of android.R.drawable.arrow.

and please share your resource folder images screen shot of names.Only if possible. Otherwise try to remove same name resourceimage drawable added by you if you added any drawable named "arrow"